# Magento 2.3.5 - Large table scconnector_google_feed_cl

Tags: magento2.3, database, google

We found a 'large' table on our completely clean Magento 2.3.5 store, that we run some indexes after we added a few products.

Is there anyone who can tell us what table `scconnector_google_feed_cl` is for and what it is creating?

Can we remove or truncate it for example?

Comment: is it safe to truncate this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was used in module Magento_GoogleShoppingAds but that module is end of life.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales-channels/google-eol.html

However, the module adds triggers to your MySQL database and sometimes, when you upgrade to e.g. Magento 2.3.6 the module, removes the table but fails to remove the triggers.

I had to run show triggers in my DB and then I had to drop the triggers before I could save product again.

```
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_website_after_insert;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_website_after_update;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_website_after_delete;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

> … the module adds triggers to your MySQL database and sometimes, when you upgrade to e.g. Magento 2.3.6 the module, removes the table but fails to remove the triggers.

⚠️ Don't just delete the triggers given above!

**FIRST verify the triggers causing it!**

```sql
show triggers WHERE STATEMENT like '%scconnector_google_feed_cl%';
```

That gives you a list of all triggers that contain the table name in their statement.

THEN! Carefully read the triggers' statements and make sure they only contain sql queries for `scconnector_google_feed_cl`.

THEN! you can delete the triggers!

In **our** case these were:

```sql
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_insert;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_update;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_delete;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_insert;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_update;
drop trigger trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_delete;
```

Rico

Answer (score 1):

Changelog tables are created by several modules on Magento 2: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html#m2devgde-mview

Using `SHOW TRIGGERS;` you can see all of them.

If your crontab is running correctly and your indexers are set to run on `Update by Schedule`, `indexer_update_all_views` will process all the changes on your catalog...

`indexer_clean_all_changelogs` cron job should clean entries on those tables every minute.